# Flagging records with all missing values on right table when doing a left join

Tags: sql, join, sas, left-join, missing-data

I have two tables representing client data for different years `Left Table: 2019` and `Right Table: 2018`. Some of these clients did not exist for the prior year and my assumption is that when doing the left join, all field values from right table will be missing for those clients. Is there a way to flag these clients (or records)? Below is my query

```
create table joinedTable as
select a.unique_number, a.monthly_spend, b.unique_number, b.email_preference, b.client_tier,
from table2019 as a
left join table2018 as b
on a.unique_number = b.unique_number
```

Below is the desired output.

| unique_number | monthly_spend | email_prefernce | client_tier | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12AB56FG | 2000 | Yes | Special | 0 |
| 32AB56FG | 1200 | Yes | Special | 0 |
| 42AB56FG | 2010 | Yes | Special | 0 |
| 56AB56HG | 3000 | Yes | Special | 0 |
| 72AB58FG | 6000 | NULL | NULL | 1 |
| 92AB56FG | 800 | NULL | NULL | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `case` expression:

```
create table joinedTable as
    select a.unique_number, a.monthly_spend, b.unique_number, 
           b.email_preference, b.client_tier,
           (case when b.unique_number is null then 1 else 0 end) as flag
    from table2019 a left join
         table2018 b
         on a.unique_number = b.unique_number;
```